# Swift closures change captured variable

Tags: swift, lambda, reference, closures

I'm using the closure like

```
{ [capturedVar] otherVar in
    // Some code here
}
```

When I try to change capturedVar, an error appears, saying it's a constant and cannot be changed. Is there any way to change captured variable inside the closure (I need the original to be changed to, so copying is not an option)?

Comment: Don't capture it ...

Comment: @MartinR, OMG, so easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Swift 2, captured *variables* are always constants and this behavior cannot be changed.

You can change the variable within the closure this way (it's a sort of trick):

```
{   [capturedConst] otherVar in
    var capturedVar = capturedConst
    // Some code here
}
```

You also have stated that you'd like to change the original variable, too:

In this case I suggest you to check the `inout` [parameter definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) or, eventually, return the new changed variable from your closure.